# Change whole rvalue array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to pass several ints in the constructor and change field of the structure like this:

```
struct testStruct
{
  testStruct(int argIntArray[])
  {
    intArray = argIntArray;
  }

  int intArray[5];
};

void main()
{
  testStruct test1(new int[5]{1,2,3,4,3});
}
```

But I can't do it like that. `intArray = argIntArray;` = "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". I can do it like `intArray[0] = argIntArray[0];`, but this is not an elegant solution.

I know I can do it with pointer notation, but is there a way to do that in array notation?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons `std::array` or `std::vector` is preferable to an array.

Comment: Use `std::copy()` to do that

Comment: @AlexanderZolkin Also, your solution is not very elegant to begin with, because `new int[5]{1,2,3,4,3}` is a memory leak as you never `delete[]` the array.  Perhaps [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) would suit you better? `testStruct(std::initializer_list<int> argInts) ... testStruct test1({1,2,3,4,3});`

Comment: `intArray = argIntArray;` is wrong. Copy entries.

Comment: A. just don't use C arrays in C++, use std::array or std::vector instead, and std::span to refer to an arbitrary contiguous list of data in memory (gsl::span can be used before C++20); B. C arrays are second class citizens in C (and then C++). Like functions, they can be declared, but they decay to pointers to their first element (i.e. &a[0]) as soon as you use them. They can't be passed by value or referenced, and they have super wonky semantics (the fact that C++ allows stuff like `T (&)[N]` doesn't help at all). Just stay away from them and your life will be easier.

Comment: @Alexander Zolkin In nay case your approach is unsafe because it is unclear how many elements are contained in the array used as the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering my limitations (I can use only C functions), `memmove()` will do the trick:

```
#include <cstring>

const unsigned int markArraySize = 5;

struct TestStruct
{
  TestStruct(int argIntArray[])
  {
    memmove(intArray, argIntArray, sizeof(int)*markArraySize);
  }

  int intArray[markArraySize];
};

int main()
{
  int testArray[5] = {1, 9, 3, 4, 3};
  TestStruct testStruct(testArray);
  return 0;
}
```

Addition.

Also I found out how to do that without extra function like `memmove()`:

```
#include <iostream>

void testFunc(const int (&array)[5])
{
  std::cout << array[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  testFunc({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

  return 0;
}
```